# Conditional - Apply After Every Third Loop

Tags: craft4, loop, count

The following is messy and obviously not scalable. There must be a way in twig to target a common difference of 3 right?

```
{% if loop.first or loop.index == 4 or loop.index == 7 or loop.index == 10 %}
    <!-- AFTER every third loop -->
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the `divisible by()` test in Twig that tests for a number being divisible by another. Twig also has an alternative to `loop.index` called `loop.index0` that starts at `0` instead of `1`. You can combine these like this to output something very third iteration of the loop:

```
{% if loop.index0 is divisible by(3) %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [remainder operator](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/templates.html#math) (`%`) or the [`divisibleby` test](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tests/divisibleby.html)!

Using the remainder or “modulus” operator:

```
{% for letter in range('A', 'Z') %}
  <p>Letter {{ letter }} is at position {{ loop.index }}.</p>

  {% if loop.index % 3 == 0 %}
    <p>I will only appear every third letter!</p>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Using the `divisibleby` test:

```
{% for letter in range('A', 'Z') %}
  <p>Letter {{ letter }} is at position {{ loop.index }}.</p>

  {% if loop.index is divisibleby(3) %}
    <p>I will only appear every third letter!</p>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```